Inferring a type from within an interface's properties
I have a memoizer that allows you to transform arguments before comparing, something like so:
function sum(x: number, y: number) { return x + y; }

const memoSum = memo(sum, {
  // receives an array of numbers ([x, y]) and converts to a string (i.e., `${x},${y}`)
  transformArgs: (args) => args.join(','),

  // receives the transformed arguments (strings in this case)
  isEqual(a, b) => a === b
})

Is there a way to write an interface that infers the type of arguments a and b iff transformArgs is provided? Something like:
interface MemoOptions<F extends AnyFunction> {
  transformArgs(args: Parameters<F>): TransformedArgsHereDefaultsToParametersF;
  isEqual(a: TransformedArgsHereDefaultsToParametersF, b: TransformedArgsHereDefaultsToParametersF): boolean;
}


Edit: Adding TS playground with the answer. Thanks for helping!

Simply add another generic type parameter:
interface MemoOptions<F extends AnyFunction, R> {
    transformArgs(args: Parameters<F>): R;
    isEqual(a: R, b: R): boolean;
}

TS Playground

But transformArgs receives F's arguments. The code will look something like: newArgs = transformArgs(originalArgs); isEqual(newArgsA, newArgsB)

I added comments to the code sample above. Basically, the result of transformArgs is passed to isEqual. I know what I'm asking may not be possible at this time...

Ah, I'm not sure why I missed that. I was tripped up by the fact that transformArgs would be optional, but providing transformArgs = (args) => args should solve that case. Thanks!
